# Size limits for images embedded in Crystal Report through .NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

hey guys,
i am running into an issue here - 
my crystal report library embedded in my asp.net web application is crashing out if a large image (>1.5 mb jpeg) file is embedded to it.

i'm trying to find the image file size threshold for that ... so far i do not have much luck on google - any thoughts on that? (if you had run into similar problems before)